# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The “path” argument must be of type string. Received type undefined

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, filepath, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

Im trying to install chaincode using fabricsdk in nodejs. installchaincode function throwing the below error:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The “path” argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
```

Below is the code:

```
exports.installChaincode =
    async function() {
  let errorMessage = null;
  try {
    // first setup the client for this org
    var client = new Client();
    let serverCertPeer = await storageUtil.getFileContent(
        '/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/tlsca/tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem',
        'fabriccerts');
    let peer = client.newPeer('grpcs://IPADDRESS:7051', {
      'pem': Buffer.from(serverCertPeer).toString(),
      'ssl-target-name-override': 'peer0.org1.example.com'
    });
    var request = {
      targets: [peer],
      chaincodePath: 'github.com/chaincode/fabcar/go',
      chaincodeId: 'fabcar',
      chaincodeVersion: '5.0',
      chaincodeType: 'golang'
    };
    let results = await client.installChaincode(request);
    // the returned object has both the endorsement results
    // and the actual proposal, the proposal will be needed
    // later when we send a transaction to the orederer
    var proposalResponses = results[0];
    var proposal = results[1];

    // lets have a look at the responses to see if they are
    // all good, if good they will also include signatures
    // required to be committed
    for (const i in proposalResponses) {
      if (proposalResponses[i] instanceof Error) {
        errorMessage = util.format(
            'install proposal resulted in an error :: %s',
            proposalResponses[i].toString());
        console.log(errorMessage);
      } else if (
          proposalResponses[i].response &&
          proposalResponses[i].response.status === 200) {
        console.log('install proposal was good');
      } else {
        all_good = false;
        errorMessage = util.format(
            'install proposal was bad for an unknown reason %j',
            proposalResponses[i]);
        console.log(errorMessage);
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(
        'Failed to install due to error: ' + error.stack ? error.stack : error);
    errorMessage = error.toString();
  }

  if (!errorMessage) {
    let message = util.format('Successfully installed chaincode');
    console.log(message);
    // build a response to send back to the REST caller
    const response = {success: true, message: message};
    return response;
  } else {
    let message = util.format('Failed to install due to:%s', errorMessage);
    console.log(message);
    const response = {success: false, message: message};
    return response;
  }
}
```

Seems like many people faced this issue in the community but there is not solution provided any where. Which path we should provide under chaincodepath param? Container path or local path?

More info: I have taken block of code from balance transfer sample app, but made few changes like reading the org details from the input instead of using connection profile file. I'm able to create channel, join channel, update channel, instantiate chaincode using the above method which works fine, but when it comes to chaincode installation its throwing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above issue comes when we don't set the gopath. We can set by using below `process.env.GOPATH = 'YOUR_GOPATH_HERE'` before sending the request.

If we use java chaincode, then you don't need to set any path :)